# <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'

Tags: python-3.x

```
def most_common_oneliner(L):
from itertools import groupby as g
return max(g(sorted(L)), key=lambda x, v:(len(list(v)),-L.index(x)))[0]
```

Here is the code above, and when I try to run it on Python 3.0 , it gives me the following error:

```
 <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'
```

Could someone tell me how to fix it, thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest fixing this by making it more readable, compacting all this code in to one line is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Please read [the docs for `max`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max):

> The `key` argument specifies a *one-argument* ordering function like that used for `list.sort()`.

The function you supply for `key` should accept *exactly one argument*, not two, like this:

```
lambda thing: (len(list(thing[1])), -L.index(thing[0]))
```